# Open dynamic images on ListView Click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hey guys I need your help working on this thing since last 4 hours but not able to get it exactly.

Actually I have many images and want to display them depending on the click on ListView

What I have done till now :

Created 2 xml files :

main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:divider="#00000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

formulas.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFormulas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/formulas" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Now what I have done with java code is have created 3 classes

1. Formulas.java

   ```
   package com.shivam.listview;

   import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class Formulas extends ListActivity {
   String name[] = {"Triangle 1", "Triangle 2"};
   String files[] = {"formulas/triangle1.png", "formulas/triangle2.png"};
   ListView lv;
   private ForAdapter mAdapter;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   if( mAdapter == null){
       mAdapter = new ForAdapter(this);
       setListAdapter(mAdapter);           
   }
   mAdapter.setData(name);
   }


   @Override
       protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
       showText(files[position]);

   }

   private void showText(String filename) {
           Intent showIt = new Intent(this, Formulas.class);
           Bundle toShow = new Bundle();
           toShow.putString("show_for", filename);
           showIt.putExtras(toShow);
           startActivity(showIt);
   }
       }
   ```

Here I am taking the position and passing the value of file[] to SetFormulas.java and passing  values to ForAdapter.java

### Basically I am not getting what exactly to do with SetFormulas how to set the images depending on the item clicked via list view.

ForAdapter.java

```
package com.shivam.listview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class ForAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
public ForAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void setData(String name[]) {
    clear();
    if(name != null){
    for (String formu : name)
        add(formu); 
    }
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, 
        ViewGroup parent){
    View view;
    if(convertView == null){
        view = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    }
    else{
        view = convertView;
    }
    String data = this.getItem(position);
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFormulas)).(data);

    return view;


}
}
```

---

SetFormulas.java

```
package com.shivam.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SetFormulas extends Activity{

ImageView ivFormulas;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.ivFormulas);
    initializers();
}
private void initializers() {
    ivFormulas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivFormulas);
    Bundle getBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    String mFormulas = getBasket.getString("show_for");
    ivFormulas.setImageDrawable(mFormulas);
}

}
```

---

Also please explain in a bit detail so that I would be able to understand and wont repeat that mistake again.

P.S : I have put the images in assets/forumlas as well as drawable/folder too.

Thanks

Comment: Image is displaying or not?? use image.setImageResource(resId); instead of ivFormulas.setImageDrawable(mFormulas);

Comment: Tried a lot of things...actually the problem is in my code...displaying the code is face away...There have been many errors...And Im not able to use image.setImageResource(resId); or any other as I have defined the image path in String...DOnt know what to do exactly...Totally confused...Have done the same for HTML files but in that case it was String only so didnt face any problem.

Comment: Here is the link of the app...You can download and import it : http://codesms.com/app/ListView.zip

Comment: if there is a string you can convert it to integer

Comment: I have already converted it into int type and passed the resource ids...but Im totally fkd up...working on it since last more than 5 hrs now...

Comment: Sorry Dude nothing happening in your code....

Comment: Yeah thats the problem like I stated off well then The things become a bit complex...and now I am here...Please see if you can help with the same...

Comment: But first of all you have to R & D that Custom list View with Image and text...So you can get that easily....and yes..I know that you can do that

Comment: Thanks for showing your confidence...Yeah I have already done that for parsing html files in my previous app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidacid.apticalc

Comment: Yeah..Its a good app and according to that code you have to just follow it...